# Find last ocurrence based on match criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets that I use to run tests for an app I developed.
The spreadsheet has two sheets, on the first ("Runs" sheet) I put the dates (in DD/MM/YYYY format), test id and result for the tests:

```
---------------------------------|
|Date        | test id  | Result
|--------------------------------|
|12/10/2014  | 1        | Passed |
|12/10/2014  | 2        | Passed |
|12/10/2014  | 3        | Passed |
|03/11/2014  | 4        | Passed |
|05/11/2014  | 1        | Failed |    
----------------------------------
```

On the second sheet I want to have the list of all the tests, and when was the last time they were executed, and also the Results for them. This is the expected output in "Tests" sheet:

```
-----------------------------------|
|test id     | Last run   | Result
|----------------------------------|
|1           | 05/11/2014 | Failed |
|2           | 12/10/2014 | Passed |
|3           | 12/10/2014 | Passed |
|4           | 03/11/2014 | Passed |
|5           |            |        |    
------------------------------------
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get the "last run" for a test.
I used the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Runs!A$3:A$9992, MATCH(A5, Runs!B$3:B$9992, 0))), "", INDEX(Runs!A$3:A$9992, MATCH(A5, Runs!B$3:B$9992, 0)))
```

But that only returns the `first match` for the test id, and not the `last one`. So, this is the output I'm currently seeing in "Tests" sheet:

```
-----------------------------------|
|test id     | Last run   | Result
|----------------------------------|
|1           | 12/10/2014 | Passed |
|2           | 12/10/2014 | Passed |
|3           | 12/10/2014 | Passed |
|4           | 03/11/2014 | Passed |
|5           |            |        |    
------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me to change the formula to make it return the last match, like the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'Test'!B1` : `=max(filter(Runs!A:A,Runs!B:B=A1))` - to find out the last date for a given test id (cell A1)

`'Test'!C1` : `=filter(Runs!C:C,Runs!B:B=A1,Runs!A:A=B1)` - to find out the result corresponding to that test on that date.

Copy down for the rest of tests

Comment: I'm having a problem with the date format, when "Date" in Runs is in DD/MM/YYYY (i.e 12/10/2014) the formulas fail, when "Date" in Runs is in DDMMYYYY (i.e 12102014) everything works. Do you know how can I make it work with the DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: post a link to your (shared) spreadsheet, and I can have a look. It should work fine with dates, so long as they are stored as DATES and not text.

Comment: They were indeed stored as text, I formatted them as DATE and now it works great, thank you!